# Problems when importing a custom Java class

Tags: import, java

I have a jar file so I tried to run the class from Mathematica following [these steps](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConnectToAnExternalJavaProgram.html), but I get all these:

```
Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Buscar
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398).

LoadJavaClass::fail: Java failed to load class Buscar.
```

This is the code in my notebook

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[]
AddToClassPath["C:\Users\Amada\Documents\Buscar.java"]
LoadJavaClass["Buscar"]
```

And this is the Java codel I made it with Apache-Neatbeans 11.2 and I have JDK 12 and Mathematica 12 (if it's useful)

```java
package buscar;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Buscar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        buscador("issue");
    }
    
    public static void buscador(String palabra){
     Scanner entrada= null;
        String linea;
        int numdelinea= 1;
        boolean contiene= false;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
         try{
            
            File f= new File("C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/12.1/Documentation/English/System/ExampleData/USConstitution.txt");
            entrada= new Scanner(f);
            System.out.println("Archivo: " + f.getName());
            System.out.println("Texto a bucar: " + palabra);
            
            while(entrada.hasNext()){
                linea= entrada.nextLine();
                if(linea.contains(palabra)){
                    System.out.println("Línea " + numdelinea + ": " + linea);
                    contiene = true;
                }
                numdelinea++;
            }
            if( !contiene){
                System.out.println(palabra + "no se ha encontrado");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println(e.toString()+ "No se ha seleccionado ningún archivo");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }finally{
            if(entrada !=null){
                entrada.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you everyone.

-Luisa

Comment: You need to either add the jar file containing the Buscar class or the actual .class file (not .java) to the classpath. e.g. `AddToClassPath["C:\\Users\\Amada\\Documents\\Buscar.class"]`

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it failed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues that must be addressed.

1. The `AddToClassPath` call should reference the directory or JAR file containing the compiled Java classes, not the source file.  Since you are using NetBeans, the class files are normally compiled into the subfolder `build\classes` within the project folder (or possibly just `build` depending on the NetBeans vintage).  Also, if it is a normal Java application project, then a JAR file will also have been generated into the subfolder `dist`.
2. When loading the Java class, the package name must be included in the class name.  In this case, `LoadJavaClass["buscar.Buscar"]`.
3. The class uses `System.out.println` to display its results.  To see this output, you must use `ShowJavaConsole[]`.

The following code puts this all together.  You will need to adjust it to match your actual project directory structure (here, *C:\NetBeansProjects\myapp*):

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[];

AddToClassPath["C:\NetBeansProjects\myapp\build\classes"]
(* or possibly: AddToClassPath["C:\NetBeansProjects\myapp\dist\myapp.jar"] *)

LoadJavaClass["buscar.Buscar"]

ShowJavaConsole[]
```

Having done all this, we can run the main program:

```
Buscar`main[{}]

(* output in the Java console:

Archivo: USConstitution.txt
Texto a bucar: issue
Línea 42: Authority thereof shall issue Writs of Election to fill such Vacancies.
Línea 545: no Warrants shall issue, but upon probable cause, supported by Oath or
Línea 699: executive authority of such State shall issue writs of election to fill such
Línea 845: Congress shall decide the issue, assembling within forty eight hours for that
*)
```

... or we can run the static method `buscador` instead:

```
Buscar`buscador["issue"]

(* same output as above *)
```

**Manipulating the Result**

You might want to consider changing the method `buscador` to return its result instead of printing it to the console.  This would make it easier to manipulate the result within *Mathematica*.  Perhaps it could return a string or list of strings... or something more structured like JSON.  But such changes to the Java code are beyond the scope of this response.

Alternatively, you could run your application directly with Java and `Import` the result (no `JLink` required):

```
Import[
  "!java -cp C:\\NetBeansProjects\\myapp\\build\\classes buscar.Buscar"
, "Text"
]

(* Same output as before, but returned as a string *)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried what you wrote but now I have a new message: `A Java exception occurred: "java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: \
buscador/Buscador has been compiled by a more recent version of the \
Java Runtime (class file version 56.0), this version of the Java \
Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0 ` I read a post in other forum about a similar situation and they said it's necessary to change the directory of the java executable, that'd work?

Comment: [Java class file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) version 55 indicates Java 11 whereas version 56 is Java 12.  You will need to either 1) download the older version of the Java SDK and use it to compile your source or 2) configure _Mathematica_ to [use a newer Java installation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromTheWolframLanguage.html#14256) (e.g. the one from your NetBeans).

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried both options but no one worked so I decided to download Netbeans 8.2 and problem solved.

Comment: Hi again, I changed my Java code and now it returns the result but I don't know how to show it in the notebook @WReach

Comment: If you have defined a method that returns `String` or `List<String>` or similar, then simply calling it from _Mathematica_ should show the result in the notebook.  If your new method is `static` then you can call it like in the example in this response.  Otherwise, you will have to create an instance of the class first.  If you have tried those things and it still isn't working, perhaps post a new question showing your updated code.